# AngularJS Dynamic routing with paramaters best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have dynamic routes and I am trying to make sure I switch states as efficiently as possible.

If I have a state for instance ex pseudo code

```
.state("apartmentDetails", {
        url: "/apartmentDetails/:id",
        templateUrl: "templates/apartmentDetails.html",
        controller: apartmentDetailsCOntroller
})
```

Will my controller take the parameter id and then for instance call a service or fetch the data (which is a list of apartment objects with pictures, prices, name of building etc and other properties)from a file then

perhaps run a function like buildApartmentTemplate() then I go and build the template and pass the data thru $scope?? this is the only way I can think of but I am sure there is a better way that doesn't involve a function that has to populate the template.  Is there a best practice that would make it more dynamic?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stackoverflow as it is **primarily opinion-based**. If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

The better option is use a promise in route definition and inject results if promise was resolved, with this approach you avoid unnecesary queries after template is loaded and, in case of promise was reject you can redirect to 404 page or whatever you want.

```js
app.service('apartamentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.list = function (id) {
       return $http({url: '/apartaments/' + id});
 }; 
}]);
  
 app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/apartmentDetails/:id/', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/apartmentDetails.html',
  controller: 'apartmentDetailsController ',
  resolve: {
   apartaments: ['$route', 'apartamentService',
    function ($route, apartamentService) {
     return apartamentService.list($route.current.params.id)
    }]
   }});
     
}]);

app.controller('apartmentDetailsController', ['$scope', 'apartaments', function ($scope, apartaments) {
 $scope.apartaments = apartaments; 
}]);
```

Hope I help you

Comment: after I get the data wil I always have to run a function like populateView() or is there someway I can pass this data to view and populate the view without calling some function populateView()

Comment: what is the function of populateView()? load the list of apartaments from server according to param in route? If this is its function, the anwser is no.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you.

What I usually do is resolve all my stuff before loading some component in your case it would be something like:

```
state("apartmentDetails", 
{ 
url: "/apartmentDetails/:id", 
templateUrl: "templates/apartmentDetails.html", 
controller: apartmentDetailsCOntroller,
resolve: {
  someResolvedData: ($stateParams) => {
     return YourService.getMyData($stateParams.id);
  }
}
})
```

Also you will need to create a binding for `someResolvedData` where your resolved data will be available on controller or in template. `YourService` is name of your service (don't forget to inject it) and `getMyData()` is some function on service that will return data.

Check more about resolving data here:

https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c

Comment: pegla I see what you mean but now after I have the data how do I populate the view without running a function called something like populateView() that passes that data and builds the template.  Is there a way I could do it without calling some populateView() function

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what are you doing in populateView() function. You get data via resolve and then you show data on template - since you have data on controller/scope wherever you want it. I don't understand what are you trying to achieve with that populate view function can you update your question? If you want to switch different template based on url slug you will need to use templateProvider and return wanted template in there based on slug.